# Linked list first and last element can't be deleted

Tags: c#, algorithm, linked-list

I made big research in this forum and found many "solutions" but none of them work.
Maybe my situation is a little bit different and I maybe someone can see where is the problem. I need to delete each Node element which is has "value" less than given(kruvis).

```
public void Delete()
{
    if (Start == null) return;

    if (Start.Next == null)
    {
        Start = null;
        return;
    }
    if (Current.Next == null)
    {
        Current = null;
    }

    Node temp = Start;
    while (temp.Next.Next != null)
    {
        if (temp.Next == Current)
        {
            temp.Next = Current.Next;
            Current = temp;
            return;
        }
        temp = temp.Next;
    }
}
```

There is another function(loop in function) in diferent class

```
for (MenesioAgentai.Pradzia(); MenesioAgentai.ArYra(); MenesioAgentai.Sekantis())
{
    if (MenesioAgentai.GautiT().Kruvis <= kruvis)
    {
        kruvioSuma += MenesioAgentai.GautiT().Kruvis;
        PasalintiAgentoPrenumeratorius(pren, MenesioAgentai.GautiT());
        MenesioAgentai.Delete();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the first and last element is not deleted
in NodeList class I have 3 nodes Start, End, Current. (and sealed class Node with T data and Node Next)

Comment: What's so terribly difficult in deleting the first (start) element in your linked list, a-la Start = Start.Next ? For deleting the last element, you have to iterate over your list to find second last element and then do kind of End = SecondLast.Next ... (oh, and you will also have to consider the case where your list has only one element with Start,End,Current all being the same element)

Comment: I tried if(Current==Start){ start=start.next return;} but it does'nt work..

Comment: I am testing my program and when I make value(kruvis) biggest number(to remove all elements, everytime first) it does'nt work, it skips first element and than removes everything until the last element

Comment: Well, if you only do `if(Current==Start){ Start=Start.next return;}` then what is `Current` referring to after this piece of code has been executed?

Comment: Debugging in VS is a powerful tool that allows you to fix this and other similar problems. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/quickstart-debug-with-managed?view=vs-2017) is a link.

Comment: If you have difficulties understanding what you do (or should do) with your linked list, i would suggest you take pen and paper and "manually" exercise the list operations  yourself on paper in a detailed step-by-step manner (including all involved "parties" such as Start,Current,End, etc.). This can both help you developing a "mental process" of what the list operations should do precisely and providing you with an opportunity to graphically visualize the process on paper.

Comment: Reading the code, it seems fairly straight forward why the first and last nodes aren't being deleted. You stated you have the nodes: `Start -> Current -> End`, and you have a `return` inside your while statement that returns after setting `Start.Next = End;`.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting node from a linked list is a bit tricky when the head node also needs to be deleted. An easier way is to add a sentinel node at the beginning. The following Java code explains how to delete nodes that have a smaller value than a given value. I used a value of type int for simplicity.

```
/*
// Node definition
class Node {
   Node next;
   int val;

   Node(int val) {
       this.val = val;
   }
}
*/

public Node delete(Node head, int k) {
    Node sentinel = new Node(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    sentinel.next = head;

    Node prev = sentinel, curr = sentinel.next;
    while(curr != null) {
        while(curr != null && curr.val < k) {
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        prev.next = curr;
        prev = curr;
        if(curr != null) {
            curr = curr.next;
        }
    }
    return sentinel.next;
}
```